# How to check if a document is read-only - VSCode extension API

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there any way to find out if the active text document is read-only or not?

I couldn't find it in [VSCode namespace API](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api) documentation.

Comment: What about just save the `TextDocument` or `applyEdit` and if the promise returns false its probably read-only

Comment: @Michael i don't want to edit or save the document on behalf of user. is there any way to without modifying the doc? I'm fairly new to VSCode extension development so dont know much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode runs on Electron that runs on NodeJS, which mean you can access the file system and check the file permissions without using VSCode API.

You can check file permission on NodeJS with `fs` native package:

```
if ((fs.statSync(document.uri.fsPath).mode & 146) == 0) {
  // document is in read-only mode
}
```

Comment: what does '& 146 == 0' mean?

Comment: `&`(AND) is binary operator so `num & 146` is binary operation whose its output is a number. more info here: http://www.xcprod.com/titan/XCSB-DOC/binary_and.html

Comment: Also, for complete list of the `mode` bit-field options see here: https://www.codingdefined.com/2014/10/alter-file-permissions-in-nodejs.html (note: the numbers in the link are in octal (8) base)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the plain node.js `fs` package, you should use the built-in [vscode.workspace.fs](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_37#_vscodeworkspacefs) API. But even that will not help with `TextDocument`s that are not representing physical files.

You could make an assumption that if the `TextDocument.uri.schema === 'file'`, you could test if it is writable using the `vscode.workspace.fs` API.

Otherwise, perhaps applying an empty benign edit e.g. inserting an empty string as suggested by @Michael would be a useful test.

Comment: Since the question was about is *document* read-only (vs is *file* read-only) this is the better answer; sadly I have found no API in vscode to allow an extension to query the EditorModel options.readOnly.

Comment: I created an issue for something related [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/206118), it might get an explanation soon. `schema==='file'` seems to be the best thing to do indeed right now.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue to make a `isReadOnly` property attached to an editor's `Tab` object.  Then it would be easy to check that `Tab` to see if the file is read-only.

See [Consider adding isReadOnly property to the Tab object](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/185045).

It needs some upvotes though.